# Creating a javascript popup box when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A bit of a different question!

Does anyone know where there is either a plugin or point me in the right direction to create something like this: http://mashable.com/2012/05/30/kings-social-media/

When you get to the end of an article a box appears in the bottom right hand side of the screen!

Any ideas?

Thanks
Ricky

Comment: It's relatively simple, Get the top position of the article container and it's height, then on scroll(of window), check to see if the scroll position is greater than the screen height minus the top of the article minus the article height. If that is true, show the dialog, else, hide it. Very similar to all of the semi-fixed position menus.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)  Also, on a personal note, I hate those things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example from [a blog I found](http://digitaldreamer.net/blog/2010/5/9/getting-browsers-scroll-position-javascript/):

```
function getScrollY() 
{
    var y = 0;
    y = document.body.scrollBottom;
    return y
}
```

Then use this as a .js include (similar to this [JSFiddle I found](http://jsfiddle.net/XAa3Y/57/)):

```
(function($) 
{
    $area.scroll(function(e) 
    {
        if($(this).scrollBottom() < $('#divToShowBoxOn').offset().left)
            alert("Zomg you scrolled to my box!");
    }
})(jQuery)​
```

where area is the place you want to measure from

Answer (score 0):

jQuery inView plugin is super awesome.  Just put a div at the bottom of your page and when it comes into view this handler will call your function.

http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/